# Reslet with GWT and Tomcat Error

Tags: tomcat, gwt, restlet

I am getting this error on startup I am using GWT 2.0.3 and Reslet RC3

```
type Exception report 

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request. 

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet adapter threw exception 
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) 
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852) 
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) 
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) 
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) 


root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.restlet.Client.handle(Lorg/restlet/Request;)Lorg/restlet/Response; 
        org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.createComponent(ServerServlet.java:423) 
        org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.getComponent(ServerServlet.java:763) 
        org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.init(ServerServlet.java:881) 
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212) 
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) 
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852) 
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) 
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) 
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

My web XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC 
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" > 

<web-app> 

        <welcome-file-list> 
                <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
        </welcome-file-list> 

        <context-param> 
                <param-name>org.restlet.clients</param-name> 
                <param-value>CLAP FILE WAR</param-value> 
        </context-param> 

        <servlet> 
                <servlet-name>adapter</servlet-name> 
                <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class> 
                <init-param> 
                  <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name> 
                  <param-value>com.tdc.Propspace.server.TestServerApplication</param-value> 
                </init-param> 
        </servlet> 

        <servlet-mapping> 
                <servlet-name>adapter</servlet-name> 
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
        </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Restlet JARs from different versions or editions have been mixed up.